# Stepper motor connected with arduino is not listening to the initial state send by python

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I'm sending data from  a python script to my Arduino board. I can succesfully communicate with the board. Based on the data send by the python, the stepper motor connected should either move forward or backward. If python is sending '0' the motor should rotate forward and if python is sending '1' then the motor should rotate backward. When i type '0' in the serial monitor the stepper moves forward and on '1' stepper moves backward. But when python is sending data at first, stepper is not moving forward or backward. Only when the state change happens(if state changes from '1' to '0' or '0' to '1'), the stepper either moves forward or backward. I tried to see if data is send from python, the arduino is receiving data from python. Suggestion will be heavily appreciated.

Ardunio code

```
static const int SELENOID_PIN = 2;
static const int OPEN = '0';
static const int CLOSE = '1';
static const int STEPS = 30;
static const int delaylegnth = 10; 
void setup() {

   //establish motor direction toggle pins
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT); //CH A -- HIGH = forwards and LOW = backwards???
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT); //CH B -- HIGH = forwards and LOW = backwards???

  //establish motor brake pins
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT); //brake (disable) CH A
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT); //brake (disable) CH B


  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial){}//wait until the serial port is connected
  Serial.write('1');
  pinMode(SELENOID_PIN  ,OUTPUT);
}


void polarisingA()
 {
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);  //ENABLE CH A
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH); //DISABLE CH B

  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);   //Sets direction of CH A
  analogWrite(3, 255);   //Moves CH A

  delay(delaylegnth);
 }


void polarisingB()
{
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);  //DISABLE CH A
  digitalWrite(8, LOW); //ENABLE CH B

  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   //Sets direction of CH B
  analogWrite(11, 255);   //Moves CH B

  delay(delaylegnth);
}



void polarisingC()
{
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);  //ENABLE CH A
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH); //DISABLE CH B

  digitalWrite(12, LOW);   //Sets direction of CH A
  analogWrite(3, 255);   //Moves CH A

  delay(delaylegnth);
}


void polarisingD()
{
  digitalWrite(9, HIGH);  //DISABLE CH A
  digitalWrite(8, LOW); //ENABLE CH B

  digitalWrite(13, LOW);   //Sets direction of CH B
  analogWrite(11, 255);   //Moves CH B

  delay(delaylegnth);  
}

void stepRight()
{
    polarisingA();
    polarisingB();
    polarisingC();
    polarisingD();
}
void stepLeft();
{
    polarisingD();
    polarisingC();
    polarisingB();
    polarisingA();
}
void spin(bool dir,int tickes)
{
 //Serial.print(dir);
  for(int i =0 ; i < tickes; i++)
  {
    if(dir == true)//right
    {
      stepRight();
    }
    else
    { 
      stepLeft();
    }
  }
}
void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0)
  {//there is incoming data form the serial and serial is setted up
    handleData();
  }
   delay(5);
  }
void handleData()
{
  unsigned char a = Serial.read();
  Serial.write("new data");
  int action = -1;
  if(a == OPEN)
  {
     action = 1;
  }
  else if(a == CLOSE)
  {
  //Serial.print("close");
     action = 0;
  }
  if (action != -1)
  {
    bool dir = action == 1 ? HIGH : LOW ;
    spin(dir,STEPS);
    digitalWrite(SELENOID_PIN ,action ? HIGH : LOW );
    Serial.write(a);//ack
   }
 }
```

Python code(Part only sending data to arduino):

```
def openthedoor(set_accepted_list,set_list_ant_id,set_forbidden_list,set_accepted_list_frozen):
    if(((len(set_accepted_list)) >0) & (set_forbidden_list == set()) & ((set_accepted_list_frozen == None) or ((set_accepted_list_frozen & set_accepted_list)== set_accepted_list))):
        print"yes,open the gate"
        use_step(1)
    else:
        print"no,close the gate"
        use_step(0) 
def establishing_connection():
#serial.Serial("COM1",9600)
    print ser.read();
last_action = -1 

def use_door(activate):
    global last_action
    #global serial
    if(last_action != activate):
        send_data(activate)
    last_action = activate  

def send_data(data):
    global ser
    try:
        if(ser == None):
            ser = serial.Serial("COM1",9600,timeout = 0)
            print "reconnect"
        if(data==0):
           ser.write('0')
           print "python is telling the arduino to move stepper forward"
        else:
           ser.write('1')
           print "python is telling the ardunio to move stepper backward"
        time.sleep(0)

    except IOError:
         time.sleep(0)
         ser.close()
         #continue
         ser = None
    print "after read"
```

Comment: What do you want to happen?  What do you want the initial state of the motor to be?  I'm not sure from your question what your expected result is.

Comment: This Python code has invalid indentation.

Comment: @gre_gor I'm curious, by what means did you check that?  I'd love to learn that trick, if there is a trick to it.

Comment: @JLH You try to run it and see if the interpreter complains.

Comment: @JLH I want to  rotate the stepper motor clockwise or anticlockwise based on the value returned by the function use_door. If  ser.write is '1' then the stepper should rotate forward and if ser,write is '0', the stepper should move clockwise else, anticlockwise. Currently even if ser.write is '1', the stepper won't rotate forward.

Comment: @gre_gor fixed.

Comment: Your `analogWrite()` calls make no sense - you're never turning them off, so as soon as you've made one full step, those calls are not doing anything since both of the analog pins are permanently on.

Comment: @jasonharper ok. Can u give any suggestion to get rid of this?

Comment: The problem is when i initially run the python code, the arduino is not receiving any information or the handledata() function is inactive.  But once the state change happens, it works fine. Can anyone tell me what is the reason for this?

Comment: @jasonharper how does it matter?

Comment: solved the problem.